# Select elem with href not starting with some string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have links like this:

```
<a href="my:stuff">My Link</a>
<a href="other:stuff">My Link</a>
<a href="test:stuff">My Link</a>
<a href="test:stuff">My Link</a>
```

I want to select links with `href` that doesn't start with "`test`"

I've tried the following but they don't seem to work:

```
$('a[href!^="test"]')
$('a:not([href^="test"]')
```

I don't want to use `$.filter` or anything like that. Is there a way to do this with selectors alone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!^=` selector does not exist. However, your second selector should work after including the closing parentheses ')'.

```
// Incorrect syntax
$('a:not([href^="test"]')

// Correct syntax
$('a:not([href^="test"])')
```

or you can choose to use the `.not()` method instead of the `:not()` pseudo-selector:

```
$('a').not('[href^="test"]')
```

Here's a proof-of-concept of the [first](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/kkZ9C/1/) (using `:not()`) and [second](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/kkZ9C/) (using `.not()`) solutions.

Comment: @Vic I'm glad you found the problem and it works now :)